# How to quickly detect incorrect password in encrypted file without compromising security?

Tags: encryption, hash, passwords

I am developing a software to encrypt/decrypt files/streams using symmetrical encryption algorithm. During encryption phase data wil be compressed and encrypted.

When decrypting data, I want to be able to check whether supplied password is correct. For that purpose encrypted file contains header (which I would like to keep as small as possible), where some signature derived from password is going to be stored.

There are several condition that must be met:

A. Password checking must be as fast as possible and it should not require excessive CPU/memory resources. Risk of using weak/guessable password is NOT present as we declare in advance that only secure, long, random passwords are going to be used for encryption.

B. If we encrypt the same plaintext file twice with the same password, the header and encrypted text must not be the same.

I assume that a theoretical attacker has complete source code of my software. The one and only thing that the attacker does NOT have is password.
My question is - what kind of signature should I use so the security is not compromised?

Here are possible options that I was thinking about and my commentary to them:

1. Password hash (SHA, MD5, etc.). Probably not a good idea because of risk of precomputed dictionary attacks.
2. Hash of the salted password. Salt is going to be generated using pseudo-random number generator (PRNG). The initial seed of the PRNG is derived from the password. I suspect this won't help at all since we know that the attacker has access to the source code - so the attacker will always be able to generate salt for the given password and, hence, generate the hash. Then the attacker can write proprietary software which will be able to perform dictionary attack agains files encrypted with my software using our own hash-generating algorithm.
3. Using key derivation function (KDF), like PBKDF2. This does not meet condition A, because all good key derivation functions should deliberately use excessive CPU/memory resources.
4. Using HMAC. I am not very good at understanding HMAC, but I think that in this case HMAC would not be used for what it was designed. I don't need to verify integrity of the password AND the encrypted file (or, in cryptographical terms, key and the message). I just need to verify whether the password is correct.
5. Other options?

I would be grateful if someone who understands cryptography better than me could give me some ideas or comments.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you can't force this check after decrypting the file?  After all, no matter how expensive you make this check, the attacker can decrypt the file (based on a trial password), and see if that decryption is plausible.  Hence, any check you force which is more expensive than that can be ignored by the attacker (while the legitimate user still has to pay for it).

Comment: The reason is that I need to know in advance whether provided password is correct. True, I can start decrypting/decompressing file using wrong password - which should end very early because decompression will fail, but would like to avoid this.

Comment: Concerning passwords, in my realisation bruteforcing possibility is virtually excluded, since all passwords are long (>64 characters) random sequences of unicode characters. Human interaction (I mean entering passwords) is completely avoided, because data encryption is used for communication between different modules of a bigger software system. I am well aware of the fact that sharing symmetrical keys between system modules is another security problem, but this was not a part of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect job for a Key Based Key Derivation Function or KBKDF. Generate two keys from the input (salt and password). One is stored directly in front of the ciphertext and one is used as encryption key. Because the KBKDF is based on PRF it cannot be reverted, so the keys are not related as far as an attacker is concerned.

Currently the best KDF is arguably HKDF. It contains both an extract functionality (to handle long passwords) and can take a salt and `OtherInfo` structure as input. The `OtherInfo` can be used for inserting an ASCII string identifying the key, e.g. "KCV" (key check value) and "ENC" (encryption). It is possible to derive the IV by using "IV" of course, in case the salt is already random for each encryption. You may want to perform only one *extract* and three *expands* of HKDF.

I would strongly recommend authenticated encryption. Make sure you use a fresh salt for each encryption procedure.

Comment: I think that is valid only if " _long, random passwords_" is really long and random enough to be a key not needing stretching; e.g. has 22 letters randomly chosen among `0…9A…Za…z`, giving next to 131 bits of entropy. I fear this solution (perhaps any) seriously cuts corners on security for anything a human can be expected to memorize, or routinely key-in.

Comment: @fgrieu True, if the long random passwords are neither, then the HKDF extract should be replaced by e.g. PBKDF2. The direct use of HKDF here is due to the requirements in the question. Other readers should be especially wary of this.

Comment: Hello Maarten,
I have a strong feeling that this is exactly what I am looking for :-)
Could you please check my algorithm and tell whether it is correct?


I have function HKDF, which takes parameters as defined here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5869
Parameter 1: Salt - non-secret random value, will be saved in file header.
Parameter 2: IKM  - input keying material. This is encryption password in plain text.
Parameter 3: Info - optional context and application specific information. Not used.

Comment: Encryption:
1. I generate completely random Salt using some source of entropy (PRNG)
2. Using HKDF, I generate a fairly long sequence of output keying material (OKM), let's say it is at least 1024 bytes.
3. I construct file header by placing two pieces of data in it:
A) Salt
B) First 32 bytes of OKM
4. I encrypt plaintext file using the rest of OKM bytes as key and initialization vector for my symmetrical cipher.
5. Done.

Comment: Decryption:
1. I read two values from header: Salt and first 32 bytes of OKM (let's call it OKM1).
2. Using HKDF and two parameters (Salt and supplied password), I generate a fairly long sequence of OKM.
3. I compare first 32 bytes of generated OKM with data from OKM1.
4. If they are identical, then supplied password is good.
5. I decrypt file using rest of OKM bytes as key and initialization vector for my symmetrical cipher.

Comment: Well, this seems to make sense to me. Is this implementation the one you meant or am I doing something wrong?
Do you think that this could be simplified even more?
Is there a way to avoid saving Salt into header? One possibility would be to use hash of the plaintext file,
but if input file is big, this could reduce performance. The other possibility is to derive Salt from password,
but I am afraid to save this kind of information in the header.

Anyway, thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: I think the authenticated encryption sounds like a good idea. That may eliminate the need for any other password validation, since using an incorrect password would cause the authentication to fail.

Comment: @kasperd Yes, a disadvantage is that incorrect ciphertext cannot be distinguished from incorrect passwords (but this can also be an advantage, and it is always impossible to distinguish wrong password / wrong ciphertext anyway). Another more serious one is that you have to validate the whole file to see if the password is correct. This may be annoying if you are decrypting an entire DVD. So some kind  of check (ckv) value can be useful next to an authentication tag.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes If the authenticated encryption is treating the entire stream as a single message, then it is correct that you would have to decrypt the entire stream in order to validate the password. But authenticating the entire stream as a single message is problematic anyway. You likely want to be able to start processing the streamed data as it arrives, and you can only process those parts that have been authenticated already. So the streamed data has to be split into smaller messages authenticated independently.

Answer (score 1):

Hash the original text, store the hash along with other auxiliary data.
Check decrypted text against the hash.  This will check the overall integrety
of the process, not just the use of the correct key.

Answer (score -2):

This is an addition to the answer of Maarten Bodewes. I have found [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec), which is file encryption/decryption utility. IMHO, anyone who is trying to solve problems similar to mine (checking passwords, encrypting files) will benefit from studying algorithm and specification of encryption/decryption process of RNCryptor. Not sure what would cryptography experts would say about their algorithm, but it looks good to me - at least for the task I am trying to solve.

Comment: I do not see that this RNCyptor solves the problem of fast check for incorrect password in its password variant (or that it can be done). Incidentally, there's a funny security near miss in [`rnc_isEqualInConsistentTime`](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/blob/master/RNCryptor-Spec-v3.md), supposed to compare the equality of bytestrings of variable length with resistance to timing attack: if `self.length`was 256 (or a multiple of that), then empty `otherData` would be a match. It does not degenerate into a security problem in the context, since we do not use 2048-bit MACs.

Comment: Well, RNCryptor is able to check password before the encryption starts - and this is exactly what I need. It generates "validator" sequence using specified password and then compares it to the validator from the file header. If both validators are the same, the password is correct. So it *solves* the problem of password checking. Concerning the bug in rnc_isEqualInConsistentTime - that's interesting, good that you noticed it, in my implementation I'll take care of it. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, so likely you are talking about [RNCyptor (draft) v4](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/blob/master/draft-RNCryptor-Spec-v4.0.md). In the password mode, my reading is that checking a password using the validator still requires the expensive password-entropy-stretching with PBKDF2 (which BTW is far from state of the art, we have [scrypt](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-josefsson-scrypt-kdf-03) giving orders of magnitude more stretching)

Comment: Exactly, I was talking about draft v4. My bad, should have specified that. Concerning PBKDF2 - this is not a problem in my case per se, since all I wanted to know how to check password *before* trying to decrypt data. I will also have to check scrypt, I agree that it would be a better choice than PBDKF2.

Comment: I'm glad that your problem seems solved, but I do not understand how if you use RNCyptor's Password-based encryption: the validator in RNCyptor (draft) v4 does NOT much help to quickly check if the password is correct. It does save computing HMAC, but except for very large packets or small PBKDF2 parameters it is not a significant time saver, since the running time is dominated by the stretching of PBKDF2, which (as apparent [here](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/blob/master/draft-RNCryptor-Spec-v4.0.md#password-based-decryption)) must be performed before the validator check.

Comment: Fgrieu, not that it would change something, but I'll try to explain once again - I wanted a method that would allow me to check whether provided password is correct or not. Yes, using PBKDF2 slows this process a little bit, but since I am not trying to brute-force here, in my case this delay is negligible. Anyway, to check whether password is correct I have either to implement a validator sequence (as RNCryptor does), or just try to start decrypting/decompressing data without password validation.

Comment: If I use validator and supply invalid password, I get (not immediately, but relatively quickly - because of PBDKF) very clear error message saying that password is incorrect. If I don't use validator, I just have to try to decrypt/decompress until decompression returns an error (and it will, if I provide incorrect password). In this case decompressor will return error message saying that file is corrupted - because decompressor will be supplied with already decrypted data (which are going to be invalid) and decompressor has no idea at all that data were encrypted before.

Comment: And in this case, returning error saying that file is corrupted would be wrong - because file is not corrupted, it is the password that was invalid. So as you see, without using validator, decryption/decompression can return only two values - either OK or file is corrupted. And I need it to be able to return three values - OK, invalid password, file is corrupted. That was my point and the whole reason why I need to check whether provided password is correct before I start decrypting/decompressing it. That's all.